# magento product import don't show in database

Tags: database, magento, import, product

I was importing 17 products to magento yesterday. The import was smooth without error. However, after the upload only 13 products was imported. The first 4 were missing. They didn't even exist in the database. I tried to import those 4 items separately or even individually but same thing happened. Everytime it said upload was successful but nothing imported.

All 17 items are similar only different in some contents.

I am new to magento and just wondering what could cause a successful upload without actually uploading anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have unique sku for all products. same sku should not repeat

Comment: They are unique sku's. But a some part of the sku is simiar. I did notice all of the sku using the same naming structure didn't get imported no matter what i tried.